# How to get port information for usb ports using libudev?

Tags: c, linux, usb

For a small project i am using libudev to get notification for USB devices plug-in/plug-out.
Is there any way of knowing which USB port was used to plug in the device via libudev.
Actually there are multiple ports available and it is necessary to know which one was used.
Any hints would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of a research i found that it is possible using libusb.
From [here](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__dev.html#ga14879a0ea7daccdcddb68852d86c00c4), libusb can be used to get a list of all devices plugged in , now the devices discovered using libudev can be checked in the list of devices available via `libusb_get_device_list`.

Further `libusb_get_port_number` could be used to get the port number for the same device.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `lsusb` command and doing a `grep` to find the line with the name of the device. This command will output all sorts of useful information about all connected USB devices. You can also use `lsusb -v` to get very detailed info.

Check out the manpage for lsusb 
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/lsusb.8.html

Comment: Actually it is c/c++ code which and not a script. Ideally on device plugin some decisions are to be taken, for detection i am using libudev library which provides C interfaces. I am looking for a C liibrary which can be used for the same.